# How would you store user defined conditional statements?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to store user defined conditional statements to determine what to display in future cases.

I have a template similar to 
"conditional/rule (age, gender)" -> "operator (<, >, =)" -> "value (29)" -> "result (29yearoldlist)

Currently that storage system is fine as long as there was only one condition for the result. However there needs to be support for multiple with a condition such as "and" or "or".

I have a table of lists like the below

```
Lists
====================
ID     |    Name
====================
1      |    29+ Male
2      |    29-
3      |    Other
```

I have a table for conditions like below

```
Conditions
====================================
ID    |   Rule   | Operator | Value 
====================================
1     |   Age    |    >     |  29   
2     |   Gender |    =     |  M    
3     |   Age    |    <     |  29
```

Combining the tables

```
List2Condition
==========================
ListID   |   ConditionID
==========================
    1    |     1
    1    |     2
    2    |     3
```

Would the best way to determine whether the conditions are logically required to be all met or some (AND or OR) be to store the ConditionIDs in a 4th table with a field that marries them together with the logical operator?

If any additional infomation is needed let me know. This was the best way I could think to describe the problem. I was also struggling to determine how I would search for an answer (nothing seemed to come up related).

Thanks!

Comment: It makes sense, but need more clarification on what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: This also depends on what is being used to evaluate these rules and how they come into play. Is it a human-readable application? Are these user-editable?

Comment: @tadman The rules are evaluated in PHP and would not be user-editable. My current thought process is to add a priority ranking to the lists, and the first list that it meets the criteria for is the one that it would show. The user when these are evaluated will not know of the rules.

Comment: @EternalHour I don't know how to handle having multiple conditions and being able to store whether or not they need all the conditions (AND) or some conditions (OR)

Comment: These are conditions in a SQL statement? Are these users logged in or anonymous? Need more details about how you're using these conditions. The way you are doing it now with a lookup table seems reasonable.

Comment: @EternalHour in the example above, listID 1 has 2 conditions in the list2condition table. 

Within another page (PHP) I need to be able to read the lists, and their conditions to for loop through conditions. I just don't know the easiest way to store whether these 2 list conditions should be AND or OR conditions (which obviously would get more complicated if there were 3 conditions).